# Obter data com dia da semana, número da semana, mês e ano

Tags: mysql, sql, data

Há alguma maneira de obter a data se você tiver apenas o dia da semana, o número de semana, mês e ano com o MySQL?

Exemplo:

Eu quero saber que dia é com este parâmetros:

- Ano: 2014
- Mês: Setembro (09)
- Número da semana do ano: 37 ou número Week em Setembro: 3
- Dia da semana: Quinta-feira

A resposta é "2014/09/18"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A partir do ano, semana do ano(1..53) e o dia por extenso é possivel determinar a data no formato YYYY-mm-dd,

```
%X - Ano para semana com quatro digitos, sendo o primeiro dia da semana Sunday(domingo).
%V - Semana do ano.
%W - Dia da semana por extenso.

SELECT str_to_date('201437 Monday', '%X%V %W')
```

saida:

```
2014-09-15
```

Parâmetros disponiveis para formatar [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) e [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

**[Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/45170)**

Comment: Funcionou muito bem aqui, só estou tendo um pequeno problema quando a semana é a primeira de janeiro, ele retorna nulo

Comment: Consegui, eu mexi nos parametros para formatar e ficou assim :
`SELECT  str_to_date('201400 Wednesday', '%Y%U %W')`
e funcionou

Answer (score 3):

O Mysql possui uma grande quantidade de [funções para lidar com datas](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), vale a pena dar uma lida na [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).
Você pode utilizar as funções `YEAR()` para o ano, `MONTH()` para o Mês, `WEEK()` para a semana e `DAYNAME()` para o nome do dia, por exemplo:

```
    SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';
    SET @data = "2014/09/18";
    SELECT 
        YEAR(@data) AS Ano, 
        MONTH(@data) AS Mês,
        WEEK(@data) AS Semana, 
        DAYNAME(@data) AS Dia_da_Semena
```

Você pode ainda "cravar" a string com a data na chamada de cada uma dessas funções. A desvantagem será que todas as vezes que precisar alterar a data, precisará realizar a alteração em todos os lugares, segue:

```
    SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';
    SELECT 
        YEAR("2014/09/18") AS Ano,
        WEEK("2014/09/18") AS Semana, 
        MONTH("2014/09/18") AS Mês, 
        DAYNAME("2014/09/18") AS Dia_da_Semana
```

OBS: Precisei adicionar `SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR'` porque meu MySQL está em inglês.

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';
```

Comment: Teria como pegar o numero da semana dentro do mes e nao dentro do ano?