# Como executar um bloco de código a partir de um número de itens específicos registrados na tabela?

Tags: php, sql

Não soube resumir na pergunta, mas o caso é o seguinte:
Tenho uma tabela(SQL) onde existem as colunas `nome` e `data`.
Aí com **PHP**, quero verificar o número da semana a partir da data e executar uma ação caso existam um número `x` de datas registradas para cada nome.

Exemplo:

```
NOME  |  DATA
João  |  15/04/2019
Pedro |  15/04/2019
Maria |  15/04/2019
João  |  17/04/2019
Pedro |  23/04/2019
João  |  24/04/2019
```

Quero gerar resultados tipo:

```
João tem 2 registros na semana 16.
Pedro tem 1 registro na semana 16.
Maria tem 1 registro na semana 16.
João tem 1 registro na semana 17.
Pedro tem 1 registro na semana 17.
```

Alguma ideia de como eu conseguiria fazer isso?

Comment: [Obter data com dia da semana, número da semana, mês e ano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33046/5878)

Comment: Faça um laço (for, while, etc), e para cada iteração desse laço, faça outro buscando as incidências do nome na semana.

Comment: Você pode fazer isso diretamente do banco de dados calculando o número da semana, como já indicado, e a instrução `group by` do SQL para agrupar os registros semelhantes conforme a regra que você definir. Acredito que, com isso, você já tem material suficiente para pesquisar e tentar fazer por conta. Se não conseguir, pode voltar e [edit] a pergunta colocando o código feito e o resultado obtido.

Answer (score 0):

Usando sua tabela de exemplo você poderia fazer uma consulta no banco desta maneira:

```
SELECT count(*) AS qtd, nome, WEEK(`data`) AS semana FROM semanas_tbl GROUP BY semana;
```

Nesse caso o resultado de sua consulta seria

```
qtd |   nome    |   semana
4   |   João    |   15
2   |   Pedro   |   16
```